# Nokia PC suite on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bluetooth, nokia-pc-suite

Is there any convenient way to transfer images and sync it with my local folder via bluetooth, on Linux.

Nokia PC suite on Windows is a Crapware. I don't want to use it anyway.
The new Ovisuite is written using Qt, yet there is no port on Linux, sucks.

All I need is an application that stores images on the system in a folder locally and optionally deletes all of those images on the phone.

Is there an application that does that?

Answer (score 5):

[Make your Symbian phone talk to your Linux computer](http://symbianism.blogspot.com/2008/10/linux-and-symbian-pc-suite-alternatives.html) at the [symbianism](http://symbianism.blogspot.com/) blog.

> To make things worse for Linux users, PC Suite doesn't work under WINE.
>   [but] There are ways to close the communication gap a little.

Some links from that article.

1. [Wammu](http://wammu.eu/) (front end to [Gammu](http://www.gammu.org/))

   - [KMobile Tools](http://www.kmobiletools.org/)
   - [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/)
   - [Phone Manager](http://live.gnome.org/PhoneManager)
   - [Nokia Map Loader Alternative](http://nokiamaps.site666.info/)

---

And, UbuntuForums: [HOWTO: Sync Nokia E-series Phone with Evolution via Bluetooth](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=1998822)

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Wammu](http://wammu.eu/), which is a GUI frontend to [Gammu](http://www.gammu.org/) CLI tool for managing mobile devices

Comment: "Currently gnapplet is not compatible with 3rd generation of Symbian" http://bit.ly/ve8bI

But thanks, anyway!